# Drop down menu that show new link on 2 columns

Tags: css, html

I am building my website.
I am pretty new to CSS and i have 2 question.
I managed to make a drop down menu which satisfy me. The problem is that:

1)I want the white margin bottom bar when i mouseover a the 1st group of link inside the box instead than outside. I know there is a command to achieve this, but i need to fix width and height which I don't want.

2) I want the second ul element to be showed like a table with 2 column and a title for each column that is a link in bold. I can't understand why each link has it's own box around him even if i use inline.

THis is my HTML:

```
    <div id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Ispirazioni</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Chi Siamo</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">La Storia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Oggi</a></li>

                </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Articoli</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Articoli in promozione</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Catalogo ></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
    </ul>
```

And this is my CSS:

```
#menu {
clear:both;
width:100%;
height:64px;
text-align: center;
top:40px;                            /* I want the menu bar follow the scroll*/
position:fixed;              /*and it stay 40px from top        */                  
background: rgba(89,89,172,0.7);         /*I want the background is transparent*/               
}

#menu ul li{
    position:relative;         /*I want the menu element is displayed in ROW*/
    display:inline;
}

    #menu ul li a{
        text-decoration:none;
        display:inline-block;    /*menu element is separated by 20px*/
        padding:20px;       
    }

        #menu ul ul{
            display: none;        /*menu is hidden*/
            position:absolute;  /* position depends from the first ul*/             
            margin:0;
            padding:0;
            text-align:left;
        }
                #menu ul ul li{
                    display:inline;  /*my submenu width*/
                    width:300px
                }           


                    #menu ul ul li a{
                        width:300px;
                        padding:2px;
                        font-size:12px;                 
                    }
#menu ul li:hover  ul {
    display: block; 

}           
#menu ul li:hover ul a{
        text-decoration:none;
        background:rgba(89,89,172,0.7);                 
    }
#menu ul li:hover > a{
    color:blue; 
    border-bottom: 10px solid #CCC;  /* border bottom, i want inside*/
            }       
#menu ul li:hover ul a:hover{
        color:blue;
        border-bottom:none;

}
```

Sorry if my code is poor but i justy started css.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZjLdK/
Here is a fiddle, the white bar that appear when i mouseover the link is outside the box, and i want it inside. And then i want 2 column with clickable link, not a box for each sublink.

And the background always trasparent

THank you so much!

Comment: How abt creating a fiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZjLdK/
Here is a fiddle, the white bar is outside the box, and i want it inside. And the i want 2 column with clickable link, not a box for each sublink.THank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were thinking of having done? css:

```
ul {
 position:fixed;
 top:40px;
 text-align: center;
 display: inline;
 margin: 0;
 list-style: none;
 width:100%;
 background: rgba(89,89,172,0.7);}
ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin-right: -4px;
 padding:0px;
 position: relative;
 width:20%;
 cursor: pointer;}
ul li:hover {
 background: #555;
 color: #fff;}
ul li ul {
 text-align: left;
 display: inline;
 margin: 0;
 opacity: 0;
 width:700px;
 position:absolute;
 top:100%;
 left:0px;
 visibility: hidden;
 list-style: none;}
ul li ul li { 
 display: inline-block;
 width: 300px;
 position: relative;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background: #fff;
 cursor: pointer;}
 ul li ul li:hover {
 background:rgba(89,89,172,0.7); }
ul li:hover ul {
 opacity: 1;
 visibility: visible;}
```

html:

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">Ispirazioni</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">Chi Siamo</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">La Storia</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Oggi</a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Articoli</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">Articoli in promozione</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Catalogo ></a></li>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">Contatti</a></li>
</ul>
```

And here's the fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/aNVam/230/

Comment: Yes it's almost this, what i was doing wrong?
I mean, why u can use 2 column and i cant with my code?